# waitFor() method returning null although the process is finish

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
private static model connectRemoteSession(String accountName,String password) throws IOException{



            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();



            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();


            String com = // some command

            proc = runtime.exec(com);
            Worker worker = new Worker(proc);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    proc.getErrorStream()));
            String outLine;
            String errLine;
            worker.start();
            try {
                worker.join(300000);
                if (worker.exit != null){
                  //read the outout and error stream and take actions accordingly

                }

                else{
                    proc.destroy();
                    while ((outLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        CloudBackup.logger.info("online exchange output line    ="+outLine);
                        output.append(outLine);
                    }
                    while((errLine = stderr.readLine()) != null){
                        CloudBackup.logger.info("online exchange error line ="+errLine);
                        error.append(errLine);
                    }

                    throw new TimeoutException();
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                worker.interrupt();
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                throw ex;
            } finally {
                proc.destroy();
            }


        }catch(Exception e){
            CloudBackup.logger.severe(e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            reader.close();
            proc.getOutputStream().close();
            stderr.close();
        }

        return model;

    }

    class Worker extends Thread {
    private final Process process;
    Integer exit;
    Worker(Process process) {
        this.process = process;
    }
    public void run() {
        try { 
            exit = process.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
            return;
        }
    }
```

This issue I am facing is one one machine the code is working fine but on another machine the worker.exit is always null, although I put the logs in the worker.exit == null and saw that the process is getting over but somehow process.waitFor is not capturing it.

I know that process.waitFor() is available in Java 8 so I checked the version on both the machined and they have same version Java 8. Also there is no other thread running.

Comment: I see a dangerous catch in your Worker.run

Comment: This is not a case of the `waitFor()` method returning null. It is a case of *your* method not setting a variable in the event of an exception. Your code doesn't make much sense. You should read the process streams *before* calling `waitFor()` or `exitStatus().` Otherwise the process can block producing output and never exit at all.

Comment: In case of exception my variable will be null and thats what I am checking later. So I dont think that would be a issue. I am reading the process stream before calling waitFor(). After getting the exit status I am just checking the stream logs, so how does it matter?

Comment: Rubbish. You are *not* reading the process streams before calling `waitFor().` You are (i) starting the `waitFor()` thread, (ii) joining it, and (iii) reading the streams if and only if the exit status isn't null. I have already explained what's wrong with that. You are also calling `proc.destroy()` before attempting to read its streams, which makes even less sense. Try fixing it instead of arguing. NB `Process.waitFor()` has been there since JDK 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it can be a caching issue.

```
 volatile Integer exit;
```